# Is there any possibility to get a cup of Single Origin coffee when you grind Blended coffee beans?

Tags: beans, grinder, coffee-blends

*Blended* coffee is mixed by several different kinds of coffee beans while *Single Origin* or *SOE* coffee uses only one type. Given a background where you bought a bag of *blended* coffee beans and now trying to grind it by yourself for a cup of morning coffee. As the bean bag was not packaged/mixed evenly, the beans you put inside the grinder are therefore not according to their "*blended*" percentage as expected. As a result, can I say every cup of *blended* is unique due to the random bean ratio, and it may have an extreme case where the *blended* coffee you drink is actually a *Single Origin* one?

Comment: that appears to be more of a statistics question, maybe better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @ths Yep but this becomes a very simple question in mathematics cause everything could happen even with a extremely small probability. Anyway, thx for ur reply, and wish u have a nice cuppa coffee today :D

Comment: In some cases I could imagine the blend contains whole beans of two varieties that are distinguishable visually.  As you are "now trying to grind it by yourself," there is the prospect of sorting the beans in a way that *increases* the chance of getting enough beans of a single origin to brew a cup.

Comment: @hardmath Yes that's true. Thx buddy :D